# Ionic Cordova: Custom handling of push notifications with Firebase and FirebasePluginMessageReceiver

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on a mobile project using Ionic and Cordova (supporting Android and iOS) where we need push notifications.  This is the first Ionic/Cordova project I've worked on, so I'm not really familiar with it.

I've started using Firebase to support push notifications, and I successfully got the firebasex plugin working and receiving push notifications.  However, we need to be able to filter the push notifications so that only certain users will see them.

I found the GitHub page for the [Firebasex plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex#example), which mentions the following:

> Custom FCM message handling
>
> In some cases you may want to handle
> certain incoming FCM messages differently rather than with the default
> behaviour of this plugin. Therefore this plugin provides a mechanism
> by which you can implement your own custom FCM message handling for
> specific FCM messages which bypasses handling of those messages by
> this plugin. To do this requires you to write native handlers for
> Android & iOS which hook into the native code of this plugin.
>
> Android
>
> You'll need to add a native class which extends the
> FirebasePluginMessageReceiver abstract class and implements the
> onMessageReceived() and sendMessage() abstract methods.
>
> iOS
>
> You'll need to add a native class which extends the
> FirebasePluginMessageReceiver abstract class and implements the
> sendNotification() abstract method.
>
> Example
>
> The [example project](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex-test) contains an example plugin which
> implements a custom receiver class for both platforms. You can test
> this by building and running the example project app, and sending the
> notification_custom_receiver and data_custom_receiver test messages
> using the built-in FCM client.

I've had a look at the example project (linked above) and was able to build & run it and send custom messages to it.  It defines a CustomFCMReceiver class, which derives from FirebasePluginMessageReceiver, and is within a custom Cordova plugin that they call CustomFCMReceiverPlugin.

I'm trying to add a custom FCM receiver to our own project similarly, but in our project it seems it is not being used.  When I send a test message to our app, it looks like the default Firebase handler is showing it, and our custom FCM receiver is not being used.  But when I look at the example app, I don't see where their CustomFCMReceiverPlugin is 'hooked up' to get called instead of the default receiver when receiving custom FCM messages.

So far I'm just testing on Android.  I've created a Java class similar to what they have, successfully got our custom Cordova plugin installed in our project, along with a JavaScript similar to their customfcmreceiver.js.  However, it acts like the receiver I add with its registerReceiver() is not being called.

I'm wondering what I might be missing?  What's the step that allows the custom receiver plugin to work with Firebase?